# Deleting child entry with 'has_many' relationship, 1:many relationship

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Based on http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships

Let's say I have 2 Models; with 1 User : Many Posts relationship. How would I delete all posts of a selected user?

**Model_User**

```
    protected $_has_many = array('posts' => array());
```

**Model_Post**

```
protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'user' => array(
        'foreign_key' => 'author_id',
    ),
);
```

I tried `$user->posts->delete()` but it doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

Just want to add that `remove()` doesn't actually work for this case, that can only be used for `has_many 'through'` relationship.

```
 * @param  string $alias    Alias of the has_many "through" relationship
 * @param  mixed  $far_keys Related model, primary key, or an array of primary keys
 * @return ORM
 */
public function remove($alias, $far_keys = NULL)
```

*orm/classes/kohana/orm.php*

Answer (score 1):

You could try `$user->remove('posts');`

Comment: That doesn't work. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think `remove()` can only be used for `has_many 'through'` relationship. It only removes the relationship from the `'through'` table.

Comment: Did you try it? You could read the source of the remove method and check whether it does the thing you want.

Comment: Yup I did, pls refer to my edited post. The relationship I mentioned is a `has_many` without `'through'`.

Comment: @ephemeron There isn't `through` table.

Comment: I'm not sure how to phrase it. Basically if I have the following tables: `users` > `user_roles` > `roles`; `user->remove('roles')` will delete the entries from `user_roles`(the *'through'* table) that connect `users` to `roles`. This is different from my case, `users` > `posts`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out that this used to work. Not anymore for Kohana 3.2...

`ORM::factory('posts')->where('user_id','=','1')->delete_all();`

That's the closest I can get to using ORM for what I wanted.

I decided to add my own delete_all to the Model_Post. So i can do this `ORM::factory('posts')->delete_all($user_id)`

```
public function delete_all($author_id){
    DB::delete('posts')
        ->where('author_id','=',$author_id)
        ->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just met the same problem with remove function, it just wasn't made to be used with _has_many relationship, only for has_many through, but It can be easily fixed, I've extended ORM model and used following function instead:

```
public function remove($alias, $far_keys = NULL)
{
   $far_keys = ($far_keys instanceof ORM) ? $far_keys->pk() : $far_keys;

   if(NULL !== $this->_has_many[$alias]['through'])
   {
      $table_name = $this->_has_many[$alias]['through'];
   }
   else
   {
      $table_name = ORM::factory($this->_has_many[$alias]['model'])->table_name();
   }

   $query = DB::delete($table_name)
              ->where($this->_has_many[$alias]['foreign_key'], '=', $this->pk());

   if ($far_keys !== NULL)
   {
      // Remove all the relationships in the array
      $query->where($this->_has_many[$alias]['far_key'], 'IN', (array) $far_keys);
   }

   $query->execute($this->_db);

   return $this;
}
```